# Linux: Emulate Scrolling using Mouse plus *Keyboard* Modifier

Tags: linux, macros, keyboard, mousewheel

I would like to emulate scrolling horizontally/vertically by moving my mouse cursor around while holding down a keyboard modifier.

I already know how to do this by assigning EmulateWheel/EmulateWheelButton in xorg.conf... however,

what I would like is to use Super as the modifier instead of a mouse button.

Possible? I have searched all day for an answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am too late but i just figured out how to do this with mouseemu in ubuntu.
Just install mouseemu by:

> sudo apt-get install mouseemu

and edit "/etc/default/mouseemu" and add the line:

> SCROLL="-scroll 126"

126 is the key scan code for the right super key. you can find other key codes by using showkey in the terminal.
now restart mouseemu:

> sudo /etc/init.d/mouseemu restart

In ubuntu the right win key is also bringing up a list of shortcuts. I have not figured out how to disable that properly, because I also use the right win key as the compose key, so the list is already disabled that way.

A weird side effect of mouseemu is it is messing with the caps/num/scroll lock lights on my keyboard and turning them off. But I kind of like that, once I learned why they weren’t working.

Comment: Does any of this work with a touchpad? I would like to stop it from scrolling unless I am pressing the Super key.

Comment: Note: for me it didn't work by editing the file /etc/init.d/mouseemu but it worked by simply typing the command 'sudo mouseemu -scroll 126'